# Get LogonAs account value from a Service using powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I have a service running with a service account. I have a logged into the machine using administrator account. I want to find username using which the service is running.

I tried below

```
"Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name='myservicename*'" | 
Select Name, @{Name="UserName";Expression={$_.GetOwner().Domain+"\"+$_.GetOwner().User}} | 
Sort-Object UserName, Name"
```

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'myservicename%'" | Select-Object Name,StartName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Bill_Stewart mentioned in the comment, it worked for me

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'myservicename%'" | Select-Object Name,StartName
```